# Python: Mock Patch module that's used in an array

Tags: python

Here is my method:

```
def _eda_workflow(self, workflow_id, account_id):
    uuids = [str(uuid.uuid4()) for x in range(2)]

    return {
        'id': workflow_id,
        'root': uuids[0],
        'accountId': account_id,
        'steps': [
            {
                'this': uuids[0],
                'next': [uuids[1]],
                'type': 'on-contact-signed-up',
                'displayName': 'Sign Up',
                'constraints': {},
            },
            {
                'this': uuids[1],
                'prev': uuids[0],
                'next': [],
                'type': 'on-time-elapsed',
                'displayName': 'Send the email after delay or not!',
                'delay': 'PT0M',
                'sideEffect': {
                    'task': 'sendEmail',
                    'constraints': {},
                    'mailing_data': {},
                    'email': {}
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

The problem I am having is when I write this

```
def generate_uuids():
    return ["10e6e848-dc77-4057-890e-5acd4ed9aeb3", "d8d501a7-f7e7-4423-921c-e0f39b7e1301"]

@mock.patch('path.to.uuid')
def test_translte_workflow(self, uuid_mock):
   uuid_mock.uuid4.side_effect = generate_uuids
```

The return method is returning a `list` of values instead of what I am expecting. Not sure how to write this test correctly

Comment: And what are you expecting?

Comment: Sorry, I suppose that info is helpful. I am just needing to be able to `mock` two instances of `uuid4`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Side effect is just for specifying something additional to happen whenever the mock is called.  I think this is more what you were looking for:

```
def fake_uuid4():
    yield "10e6e848-dc77-4057-890e-5acd4ed9aeb3"
    yield "d8d501a7-f7e7-4423-921c-e0f39b7e1301"

@mock.patch('path.to.uuid.uuid4', fake_uuid4().next)
def test_translte_workflow(self):
   ...
```

Comment: Hmm, did you test this? A call to `fake_uuid4()` would just return a generator object. But who will iterate over that generator? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: You are correct, I should have instantiated the generator in the patch line.  Edited.

Comment: I'm still not convinced that works. This will result in a `__call__()` on the generator from his code, no? Instead of `gen.next()`. You'd need to instantiate the generator, and then create a `fake_uuid` that pulls items from it by calling  returning `gen.next()` - unless I completely misunderstand how this particular `mock` library works :)

Comment: Got me again ... does it look better now?

Comment: It works! Im not 100% sure why, but it does lol... can you give some more insight into how this is working? @wim

Comment: Patch replaces the function `uuid4` with a different callable `fake_uuid4().next`.  Inside the test_ method, when the code imports `uuid` and calls `uuid4()` it is _actually_ calling `fake_uuid4().next()`

Answer (score 2):

Your `generate_uuids` function is returning a *list* of UUIDs, so that's what you get.

If you want to create a function that returns one UUID at a time, from a pool of **exactly two** UUIDs, create an [iterator](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-iterator) from a list of two UUIDs and return `iterator.next()` from that function. If you also want to make assertions on those UUIDs, store them separately from the iterator:

```
import mock
import unittest
import uuid


TEST_UUIDS = ["10e6e848-dc77-4057-890e-5acd4ed9aeb3",
              "d8d501a7-f7e7-4423-921c-e0f39b7e1301"]


uuid_pool = iter(TEST_UUIDS)


def generate_uuid():
    return uuid_pool.next()


def func():
    uuid_1 = uuid.uuid4()
    uuid_2 = uuid.uuid4()
    return [uuid_1, uuid_2]


class TestUUIDs(unittest.TestCase):

    @mock.patch('uuid.uuid4', generate_uuid)
    def test_uuid_mock(self):
        actual = func()
        expected = TEST_UUIDS
        self.assertEquals(expected, actual)


unittest.main()
```

Once you exhaust that iterator (after fetching two elements), it will raise `StopIteration`.

If you want to create a function that always returns just one an UUID from an endless stream of UUIDs, you can use [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle):

```
from itertools import cycle

uuid_pool = cycle(["10e6e848-dc77-4057-890e-5acd4ed9aeb3",
                   "d8d501a7-f7e7-4423-921c-e0f39b7e1301"])
```

Answer (score 1):

I needed to solve something similar and, after some experimenting, preferred using an iterable with `@patch` and `side_effect`. In my case, instead of populating an array, I was populating the return value of a function called a layer deeper than the function in my test.

```
TEST_UUIDS = ["10e6e848-dc77-4057-890e-5acd4ed9aeb3",
              "d8d501a7-f7e7-4423-921c-e0f39b7e1301"]
TEST_UUID_POOL = iter(TEST_UUIDS)

@patch('path.to.function1', side_effect=TEST_UUID_POOL)
def test_translate_workflow(self, uuid_mock):
    # function 1 is called twice in function2
    function2()
```